# NSHost -localizedName returning nil

Tags: cocoa, computer-name, nshost

I have received a crash report from one user who cannot use the login feature of my OS X app. From reading the backtrace, the problem appears to be that `[[NSHost currentHost] localizedName]` is returning `nil` (I am then inserting it into an `NSDictionary`, causing the app to crash).

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHost_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSHost/localizedName), `-localizedName` returns `nil` when sent to `NSHost` instances other than `+currentHost`, but should return an `NSString` when sent to `+currentHost`.

I can get around this by checking for `nil` and setting the hostname to some arbitrary string, but I would rather use the proper localised name for the computer. In what cases can the computer hostname be `nil`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean.